# Sql query to partiotion a data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sorting

I need to partion am SQL table into 4 equal parts Based on a given contraint (content of the column) and create appropriate 4 tables. The data looks like this:

```
Field1 | Field2 | Field3
------------------------
d11       d12       d13
d21       d22       d23
d31       d32       d43
d41       d42       d43
d51       d52       d13
d61       d62       d63
d71       d72       d23
d81       d82       d43
```

The constraint is `Field3`. Thas after the partion I should get 4 tables

```
  **Table1**


  Field1 | Field2 | Field3
    ------------------------
    d11       d12       d13
    d51       d52       d13

**Table2**

Field1 | Field2 | Field3
------------------------
d21       d22       d23
d71       d72       d23


    **Table3**

    Field1 | Field2 | Field3
    ------------------------
    d31       d32       d43
    d41       d42       d43
    d81       d82       d43

**Table4**

Field1 | Field2 | Field3
    ------------------------
    d61       d62       d63
```

How can I do it? I thought about using `group by` and after that travsersing the table line by line. Is it good / or there is better solution

Comment: Can you explain the logic you used to separate the rows between the tables?

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @total INT;
DECLARE @iterator INT;

SELECT @total = COUNT(0)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY field3;

SET @iterator = 1;

WHILE @iterator <= @total
BEGIN
  SELECT s.field1,s.field2,s.field3
  FROM(
    SELECT field1,field2,field3,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.Field3) as rank
    FROM MyTable) temp
  WHERE s.rank = @iterator);
  SET @iterator = @iterator + 1;
END
```

This ought to give you your entire resultset.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 AS (
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table 
where 
WHERE field3 = 'd13') 

CREATE TABLE Table2 AS (
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table 
where 
WHERE field3 = 'd23')
```

....

Comment: He will have to manually search all the partitions every time this way.

Comment: @sagi it is 4 tables how hard is select distinct Field3 from table

Comment: That is if it will always be 4 partitions, regardless to the first sentence. And it can't ever be dynamic like this.

Comment: So, the question is partition a table.   And your answer is fixed number of tables.